# IF Debug Preprocessor on ASPX/ASCX Without Code Behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Many of the posts here on SO and around are many years old, and all come to the conclusion that nowadays if you wanted to do something like this on an ASCX page:

```
 <% #if DEBUG %>
    <div>debug here</div>
 <% #else %>
    <div>release mode here</div>
 <% #endif %>
```

You would unfortunately have to access the code behind, and use the above directives and set a page-level variable. Then in the ascx page you would access that variable's true/false rather than the directive itself.

Well, it's 2014 now, and I wanted to see if there are any new and improved ways of doing this? I basically tried the above and it still didn't work. Can anyone suggest something else to display a line if i'm in debug mode vs. if not (hopefully without using code behind)?

Thanks!

Comment: With the above you have to set <compilation debug="true"> to what you want. I think this is 'true' by default. It's in the web.config file.

Comment: if I compile my dlls in release mode it works actually

Comment: Is this a website or web app?